# "a driver at the last position" or "the driver at the last position"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Here are two sentences. I am confused about the articles **a/the**. Can you please explain to me which one is correct, and why? The sentence is:

> 1: During a road race **a** driver at the last position made a maneuver which made him take the second place.
>
> 2: During a road race **the** driver at the last position made a maneuver which made him take the second place.

Comment: Both sentences are correct for the article before the driver. However, we usually say road race, and we _take second place_ not _the_ second place.

Comment: I would also offer that the maneuver did not *make him* take second place, but *allowed him to* take second place, as other factors were probably in play as well.

Comment: We usually say ***in** the last position* (or even more likely, ***in last place***). Using the indefinite article ***a** driver in last place* more strongly implies you're making a general statement about what ***any*** driver in that position in ***any*** road race (in the past) would normally have done. But since you're presumably referring to one specific race rather than most/all races, you're also referring to one specific driver. So ***the** driver* is more appropriate (but as @Yosef says, both are "valid").

Comment: If the driver went from last to second, I would assume there were only three cars in the race.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, **the** is more appropriate because the driver we're referring to in this case was a *particular* driver in a *particular* race who had been present at the last position before he made the maneuver. Also, it is worth noting that the sentence also focuses on the *maneuver* and it's importance to the driver which won him the second place, which makes the doer of this action equally important. If we're to use 'a' in this sentence, it would imply that *any* driver could have performed this incredible feat, which apparently isn't the case here.